# "Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment." Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, nntool

Hy everybody,

I'm trying to implement a neural network with matlab using nntool.

Does anyone know what the following error message means?

> **??? Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy
>   assignment.
>   Error in ==> nntool at 694
>         [errmsg,errid] = me.message;
>
> com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabException: Insufficient number of outputs from right hand side of equal sign to satisfy assignment.**

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be that you defined your neural network with let's say N outputs, but your training data somehow has more than or less than N outputs?

Answer (score 0):

Just take the transpose of your input. If its an m*n matrix, make it an n*m matrix.